# Bash sed how to mask brackets

Tags: regex, bash, sed, raspbian

I want to search for `'start')` in the file `/etc/init.d/fhem`, and write code which I read from a textfile to that file after the statement above. At the moment I get a message that I have to close the bracket from `'start')`. I think I have to mask it properly, but so far no luck with trying that. May someone give me the missing link?

```
CocConf=$(<COC.txt)#Reading Cod from File to insert in other file
sed -r "\'start\')/a $CocConf" /etc/init.d/fhem #Inserting said Code
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `/` before the regular expression. And there's no need to escape single quotes inside double quotes. But when you use extended regexps, you need to escape parentheses. The `a` command also requires a backslash after it, and the text to be added must be on the next line.

```
sed -r "/start\)/a\
$CocConf" /etc/init.d/fhem
```